# FTP issue from embedded linux device to Windows IIS FTP

Tags: linux, ftp, windows-server-2012

We have recently installed a GPS base station, it is a high-precision GPS receiver that is used for error-correction in field GPS devices.  The device (a Trimble NetR9) uses an embedded linux OS and will FTP the data files onto another FTP server (in my case, a Windows 2012 Server with IIS).  The device is able to create the directories on the FTP server, but it can't push the files over.

I am wondering if there are settings I have overlooked on my FTP Server (Win 2012) that make it friendly to a Linux client?

**Tests tried:**

*Permissions*: To eliminate the possibility of bad permissions set, I have provided the user with full read/write permission to the ftproot folder and all subfolders, and I tried logging in as an admin user too.  The IIS settings for this user also show ‘read’ and ‘write’. Both results above still are found.  I have also tested doing the same FTP process from a workstation to the FTP server, using the same user, and had no problem putting down files.

*Network cables:*  To eliminate the (very remote) possibility that somehow network cabling was involved, we tested all the cabling from the switch to the NetR9 with a Fluke network testing tool, finding no flaws.

*Firewalls, routers, NAT, etc.:*  To eliminate the possibility that some firewall rule or router configuration I configured a Windows Surface tablet with the same exact TCP/IP settings as the NetR9, unplugged the NetR9 from its data jack, and plugged the Surface into that same jack.  Thus the Surface simulated the NetR9 from a TCP/IP perspective.  From the Surface, using FTP, there was no problem putting files on to the same FTP server with the same credentials.

*Passive/Active*: To eliminate the possibility that one of the FTP methods worked better than the other, I tried all 3 of the FTP methods on the device with no difference in the results.

*Windows Firewall:*  We checked and found that Windows Firewall was indeed turned off on this server before we ever started any of this.  We left it off.

*Windows Server:*  To eliminate the possibility that perhaps there was just something wrong with the IIS configuration on my Windows 2012 Server, we replicated the FTP server settings on an older Windows 2008 Server with IIS, and had the same exact results.

**Log file excerpt**
This is what is found in the log file after each FTP push from the device to the Widnows server.  You can see it is creating the folders, but the last part (pushing the file laco209x.T02) does not work.

2016-07-28 00:00:02   - -  -  21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 0 0 0  - -

2016-07-28 00:00:02   - FTPSVC2  -  21 USER  331 0 0 23 14 0  - -

2016-07-28 00:00:02   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 PASS *** 230 0 0 21 18 0  / -

2016-07-28 00:00:02   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 CWD t02/ 250 0 0 29 10 0  /t02 -

2016-07-28 00:00:02   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 CWD 2016/ 250 0 0 29 11 16  /t02/2016 -

2016-07-28 00:00:02   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 CWD 209/ 250 0 0 29 10 0  /t02/2016/209 -

2016-07-28 00:00:02   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 CWD LACO/ 250 0 0 29 11 0  /t02/2016/209/LACO -

2016-07-28 00:00:02   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 TYPE I 200 0 0 20 8 0  - -

2016-07-28 00:00:02   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 PORT 10,40,55,108,234,136 200 0 0 30 27 0  - -

2016-07-28 00:00:03   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 STOR laco209x.T02 550 4294967295 0 48 19 1031  /t02/2016/209/LACO/laco209x.T02 -

2016-07-28 00:00:04   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 TYPE I 200 0 0 20 8 0  - -

2016-07-28 00:00:04   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 QUIT - 221 0 0 14 6 0  - -

2016-07-28 00:00:04   \ FTPSVC2  -  21 ControlChannelClosed - - 0 0 319 142 2218  - -

I am also pursuing this with the vendor, but wanted to ask here in case anybody had seen similar behavior between linux FTP client and windows FTP server.

Comment: Do you know if it's using SSL FTP or just regular insecure FTP? You may need to ensure both TCP port 20 and 21 are available so try to open TCP port 20 if it's not and see if that makes any difference. I've not used the Windows Server FTP functionality before but with other FTP server products, you need to ensure the FTP Service account the server service is running as has access to the directories for the FTP account mailboxes in case that's what FTPSVC2 is. Can you FTP access into this server with a username and password and upload from another machine such as Windows with WinSCP, etc.?

Comment: No SSL, just straight-up FTP on port 21.  I did test the same user/passwd on an Windows table (Surface) and it worked fine.  The same thing from the Linux device does not.